# Find the element name that raises the MouseEvent in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a XAML like this:

```
<Border x:Name="ModelWindowBorder" ClipToBounds="True" MouseWheel="Func">
</Border>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void Func(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  // how can I get the element name that raised this event? (ie ModelWindowBorder)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the element by the sender argument:

```
private void Func(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)sender;
}
```

If you want to get its name, you may cast to `FrameworkElement` instead of `UIElement` and access the `Name` property:

```
private void Func(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var name = element.Name;
}
```

Comment: I thought `x:Name` set the C# member name within the surrounding Window or UserControl.  I didn't know about the `.Name` property.  If I do `ThisButton = new Button()` within the code-behind, will I automagically have `ThisButton.Name == "ThisButton"`?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala No, you'll have to set the property explicitly.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks, that reassures me.  Automagic gives me the willies, and WPF already has too much of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private void Func(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
   var name = (sender as Border).Name;
}
```